# Identifying the following JComponent

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a java application in Swing[image: my Image]. I wanted to use a Jcomponent show in the image with an arrow like pointing downwards. I could not figure out the name of the component. It is attached an icon as shown. What is the name of this component and how do we get it aligned as shown?

Currently I am using MigLayout manager. I figured out its called ChoiceBox in JavaFX, however I want it in Swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent component in Swing is JComboBox. You can just change the arrow button of the JComboBox.
For example:

```
class CustomArrowUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {
    @Override
    protected JButton createArrowButton() {
        return new JButton(new ImageIcon("resources/icon.png"));
        // If you do not want to use an image icon:
        // return new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.NORTH, Color.darkGray, Color.yellow, Color.PINK, Color.lightGray);
    }
}
```

And then...

```
JComboBox jc = new JComboBox();
jc.setUI(new CusutomArrowUI());
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a JComboBox to me after viewing http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/choice-box.htm.

Comment: @NEWSPowerGlove I tried that with an empty JComboBox but it did not look the same. Maybe this way: How do we put text at the top of it? remember this component and the text is one thing.

Comment: You could create it yourself, make a custom Swing component called like `ChoiceBox extends JComponent` give it a BorderLayout, add the text or picture or whatever you want to the north position so it takes up only the amount of room it needs, and add a JComboBox to the center. I don't think there's an exact match in Swing.